# Is this root rot?

Tags: fungus, rot

I have this plant(dont know its exact name) and had spider mite. However after spraying it seemed ok. Today it felt somewhat soft. One of them came out without much force.
Is this a root rot? What can I do? I watered it with anti-fungal. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: How old is that plant? My taro/elephant ears only lasted a dozen years or so. Initial bulb split, and I had two pretty good plants in one pot. However, when those tried to split the whole thing went downhill to the point of being a tosser. The oldest bulbs looked about like your second picture. It might be an age thing.

Comment: I don't know. Some plants that I have are unknown to shops here. Some are from 1950s. So it could be old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second picture shows the roots or what is left of them you bet this is root rot.  You plant looks healthy, new leaves as well.  Except for the root rot bit.  Did that come out of the same pot/plant?  I would transplant that plant into fresh potting soil after bleaching/cleaning the pot.

Too much water.  Don't allow the plant to sit in a water filled saucer.  Don't water unless the pot/soil/plant feels light when you pick it up.  Your other plant looks like a complete goner.  Sorry.  Too much water will kill plants.  Too much fertilizer will kill plants. Too much light will kill plants.  Too much love meant for humans will kill plants.

Are these plants in potting soil?  Did you happen to put gravel below the soil above the drain holes?  That makes drainage worse than no drain hole.  Raise the bottoms of your pots off the surface with bits of tile to get air beneath the pot.

I would transplant both plants in fresh potting soil, moisten the soil, feel the heft of those pots while moist and only water when those pots are light.  You'll easily feel the difference. We can talk about fertilizer later.

Comment: Yes it is from the same pot. The cut one was from top side.(not visible in photo).The other cut that appears in photo had rot where I cut it. My mistake was that I overwatered it. The other plant I asked agronomist and he told me that it is from sun. But I don't think so. These plants were not mine and were abandoned for 4-5 months. I am not experienced I am learning. Some pots from other plants were full of stones inside. So you suggest replanting. Should I be careful not to break root ball? How much should I cut from the rot.?

Comment: Also I found something like dead worm inside.It was like dried turned into dust easily.

Comment: The worm is no problem.  Yes, you should replant in fresh potting soil, clean the pot with a bit of bleach before adding the new soil.  No rocks.  Water only when the soil is dry, the pot feeling very light to lift.  Don't worry about being TOO gentle.  Breaking roots a bit actually helps with regrowth.  You have the qualities of a great gardener and we can help hopefully so you aren't discouraged. Try to cut off or pull off any mushy or brown roots.  Lift bottom of pot off surface or saucer with bits of tile. Use distilled water if possible.  Do you see the white residue on your pot?  Salts.

Comment: Don't wash the root ball, that is a bit stressful.  I would also get some mycorrhizae fungus to add to your soil.  This stuff is like a major help for growing roots.  Follow directions.  Go to a reputable nursery.  Dunno if Home Depot and the like will have this fungus available commercially. Root rot bacteria will be there no matter what you do.  It is sort of in the air.

Comment: I live in Europe so no 'home depot' stores here. But there are local stores that sell pesticides etc although it is illegal to sell to non professionals. Initially before asking here, I followed the advice from nursery and watered it with Thiophanate methyl 70%  and fosetyl-Al 80%.Are these ok? However they don't help much since they want to sell new plants and they told me to not bother to replant. I was very busy yesterday, I hope today to find time to replant it / wash the pot or add it to a bigger one that I have. Thanks for your help. Plant seems stable.

Comment: Well that was interesting information with Thiophanate...etc.  Hummm.  and Fosetyl....I am going to have to look into these as they mean nothing to me.  Grins...I get to learn new stuff everyday...please transplant.  I'll check into this...A nursery should give information to help you be successful.  But I don't like the information they gave you at all.  Poops!  I'll be back sweetie...

Answer (score 3):

It does seem to me by the photos that it could be root rot, but really hard to say 100%.

The best advice i can give you is to remove the plant from its pot and make sure you remove as much soil from the roots as possible, washing the roots gently is the best method for soil removeal. after replace the soil with fresh heathy uncontaminated soil.

i have searched the internet and found this helpfull page for you from the [gardening know how](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/disease/treating-root-rot-gardening-tips-for-housplants.htm) website.

Good luck and post an update on your findings